# Unable to do casting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, casting

I have this:

```
<%foreach (var item in (List<MyClass>)ViewData["something"]) {%>
```

and it throws exception: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyClass]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyClass]'.

ViewData["something"] contains one myClass object with four elements. How to solve this?

```
var xx= (from x in be.x
                 select x).ToList();
ViewData["something"] = new { xx };
```

Comment: What are you setting ViewData["something"] to in your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to cast an anonymous object with a property which is a list to a list.

To fix it, change from

```
var xx = (from x in be.x select x).ToList();
ViewData["something"] = new { xx };
```

to

```
var xx = (from x in be.x select x).ToList();
ViewData["something"] = xx;
```